# Asp.Net MVC 5 not found fileExtension .data and .wasm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service, web-config, mime-types, file-extension

I have added a .data file and another. wasm in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project and when I run it and try to call the files it tells me the following error.

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
You cannot access the requested page due to extension settings. If the page is a script, add a controller. If the file must be loaded, add a MIME mapping.

I have added the MIMEs in the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".data" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".data" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

The extensions .woff and woff2 are recognized when loading the project.
But the .data and .wasm are not.

The path to call the files is correct but it seems as if it did not find it.

The application runs on an Azure Web App.

I understand that I don't have to do anything in the IIS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but try to do

```
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".data" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".data" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
  <httpCompression>
       <dynamicTypes>
         <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
         <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
       </dynamicTypes>
     </httpCompression
    </system.webServer>
```